# AngularJS - Trouble with $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, angularjs-watch

I am trying to remove the "Red" and "Blue" drop down list options on a product SKU, if the user is a member of the "High" group on my store site. The code that I came up with is below, but only partially works; the only thing that works is the window alert. Now, if I remove the logic about looking up the user's group, then it does work, however the user has to set the value of the color drop down to begin with.

```
function SpecController($scope) {
    angular.forEach($scope.user.Groups, function (g) {
        if (g.Name == "High") {
            alert('You are in the correct group!');
            $scope.$watch('user.Groups.Name', function (val) {
                if (!val) return;
                if (val == "High") {
                    $scope.Variant.Specs.Color.Options = $scope.Variant.Specs.Color.Options.filter(function (item) {
                        return item.Value !== 'Red' && item.Value !== 'Blue';
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to put a watch on `groupName` which lies inside the each `Group` of `Groups` object. So your current watcher is pointing to `user.Groups.Name` which doesn't exist actually. If you want to make your current code working then you could take use on index while putting `$watch`

**Code**

```
function SpecController($scope) {
    angular.forEach($scope.user.Groups, function (g,index) { //added index param here
        if (g.Name == "High") {
            alert('You are in the correct group!');
            //used that index param here to put watch on each group.
            $scope.$watch('user.Groups['+ index + '].Name', function (val) { 
                if (!val) return;
                if (val == "High") {
                    $scope.Variant.Specs.Color.Options = $scope.Variant.Specs.Color.Options.filter(function (item) {
                        return item.Value !== 'Red' && item.Value !== 'Blue';
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Note**

> This solution would mess when you will have more than 1000 `groups` in
>   `user.Groups`, watcher number will increased and resultant would be
>   app will work slowly.

Comment: Ah yes, here is what it says:


 `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Specs' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as fn] (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:2533), <anonymous>:9:35)
    at h.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:106:71)
    at h.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:108:370)`

Comment: @John I can't see anything

Comment: @John could you tell me how your `$scope.user.Groups` object looks like

Comment: Here is the output:

`[{"ID":"RQMMyxWC0wqCDjGwqdtTBQ-e-e","InteropID":"","Name":"High","Description":"","IsApprovalGroup":false,"IsReportingGroup":true}]`

Comment: @John `$scope.user.Groups` can have multiple groups?

Comment: Yes, it can, but only has 1 for now - "High".

Comment: @John error clearly says that watch got fired but thing you got error is you don;t have value in `$scope.Variant`

Comment: Thank you. Is there another easier way for me to go about this? I just want to have "Red" and "Blue" removed automatically from the drop down, if the user is part of a certain group. If not, then those 2 options should appear with the rest.

Comment: @John i don't understand which dropdown you are talking about..how did you rendered dropdown?

Comment: My application automatically creates the drop down (<select>) and fills the values with ng-options.

Comment: @John  `ng-options` does use `user.Groups`?

Comment: Yes, the application generates both of them.

Comment: @John instead of putting watch you could have a filter on `ng-options` that will filter only those having `item.Value !== 'Red' && item.Value !== 'Blue';`

Comment: Did you able to figured out this?

Comment: @John Glad to help you dude.:)